# Pie Graph is drawing slices with the slices that have been already created when the activity is resumed. How do I prevent or fix this issue?

Tags: android, graph, onresume

I am using HoloGraphLibrary and using data from an adapter to generate slices. The graph works perfectly when the activity is first created.  The issue arises when the activity is resumed.  I posted two pictures, I believe they show the issue better than I can explain it.  First Image is of the graph when it is first created and the second is when the activity is resumed.  I have tried to invalidate the graph with no success.  How would I recreate the graph when the activity is resumed so it does not draw the graphs with the graphs that already exist? If you need more information, I can post more code.

**Implementation of Graph**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapters();
    pieGraph();
}

PieGraph pg;
public void pieGraph() {
    pg = (PieGraph) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    for (int x = 0; x < mSecondAdapter.getCount(); x++) {
        LogSecond lti = mSecondAdapter.getItem(x);
        String color = lti.getColorCode();
        String sdf = dff.format(lti.getTotal());
        PieSlice slice = new PieSlice();
        slice.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        slice.setValue(Integer.valueOf(sdf));
        pg.addSlice(slice);
        pg.forceLayout();
        pg.invalidate();
    }
}
```

**OnCreare**
[image]
**OnResume**
[image]

Comment: You could call removeSlices before you begin.

Comment: why do you do this: adapters(); pieGraph(); at all? they view with the attached data is still existing of cause you get double entries if you fill the adapter when the items are still existing

Comment: @Nickolaus If you could explain your question a bit more I can probably give a better answer than this.  I am trying to keep things organized because I am working with a large class.  The adapters get refreshed when the activity is resumed. If data is added in next activity and you come back, the adapters will have the new data added.  The data was not being multiplied, the graph was not removing the slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call removeslices.

```
pg = (PieGraph) findViewById(R.id.graph);
pg.removeslices();
for (int x = 0; x < mSecondAdapter.getCount(); x++) {
    LogSecond lti = mSecondAdapter.getItem(x);
    String color = lti.getColorCode();
    String sdf = dff.format(lti.getTotal());
    PieSlice slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    slice.setValue(Integer.valueOf(sdf));
    pg.addSlice(slice);
    pg.forceLayout();
    pg.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was going to be a simple answer. Ha.  Thanks for the answer, I will accept your answer as correct when the wait period is over.

Answer (score 0):

removing the slices is not the proper why to go,

call *notifyDataSetChanged* on your adapter thereby the view should be updated